# Unexpected EOF in Jenkins Ant on macOS because of password symbols

Tags: macos, jenkins, ant, continuous-integration, eof

I'm using local instance of Jenkins on my macOS machine. It configured to use macOS system Ant. I'm using `This project is parameterized` option to pass password to ant build script. But because password contains single-quote symbol I got an error:

```
/Applications/Utilities/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant: eval: line 336: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/Applications/Utilities/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant: eval: line 337: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If I'm using (wrong) password without that quote symbol, there is no same error. I'm already tried to use String parameter instead of password and add double-quotes at start and end but getting the same error.

On my Windows Jenkins instance password worked well. I have no possibility to change password so it's not the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem was caused by quote character in the password that passed to Ant from Jenkins. Simply escaping char with `\` solved my problem.